# Trying to Change src of an ImageButton in another layout folder other than activity_main

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, mobile-development

to sum up I am trying to change the src of ImageButtons inside my dialog_colors.xml file from MainActivity. However whatever I do I couldnt manage to change it. I tried the same code with ImageButtons inside my activity_main.xml but it doesnt work for buttons inside dialog_colors.xml file.

activity_main.xlm

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/dialog_colors"
    layout="@layout/dialog_colors"/> ...
```

dialog_colors.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_paint_colors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:src="@drawable/pallet_normal"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:layout_margin="1sp"
        android:tag="redTag"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="selectColor"

        />...
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    colorDialog=findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.dialog_colors)
    firstRowColors=colorDialog.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors)
    secondRowColors=colorDialog.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors2)
    drawingView=findViewById<DrawingView>(R.id.drawingView)

    pressedColor=secondRowColors[0] as ImageButton
    pressedColor!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.pallet_pressed)

}...
```

I tried the same thing with TextViews etc too. It seems like I cannot change anything inside the dialog_colors.xml file.

Do not get confused about the firstRows, secondRows etc, there are many ImageButtons, it doesnt work for any of them.

Comment: Did you try using `secondRowColors.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.red)` to get the `ImageButton` and then `setImageResource`?

Comment: @Siju that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to define an attribute in the `MainActivity.kt` through `activity_main.xml` to `content_main.xml` (included layout). The key word here is `DataBinding`. The project is completely reproducible and I provide first `Kotlin` and at the very end the `JAVA` files.

---

**KOTLIN:**

To enable `DataBinding` you need to go to your `build.gradle(Module)` and add following code:

```
//...
dataBinding{
        enabled true
    }
//...
```

You define a container called `DrawableContainer` as a `Kotlin` `class`. There you define a `Drawable` called `customDrawable`.

Thus `DrawableContainer.kt`:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

data class DrawableContainer(val customDrawable: Drawable)
```

Now we will define our `MainActivity.kt` which will bind our chosen `Drawable` and pass it through our Container (`DrawableContainer`).

Our `MainActivity.kt`:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.imagebuttonexperiment.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
            this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.drawable = DrawableContainer(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image))

    }
}
```

The missing parts are our XML files. The code below shows our `content_main.xml`. It contains a `variable` (in `<data>`) we will define named `drawable`. The `type` guides to our `DrawableContainer`. So this is the first bridge between our Container and our layout we will `<include`. In the `ImageButton` you can see that as `android:src` we refer over our `variable` to our `Drawable` in our Container. That's why `android:src="@{drawable.customDrawable}"`.

Thus `content_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <data>
        <variable
            name="drawable"
            type="com.example.imagebuttonexperiment.DrawableContainer" />
    </data>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@{drawable.customDrawable}"/>
</layout>
```

Now it's important to build our second bridge. Yet, we have `DrawableContainer` -> `content_main`. This will be the bridge `content_main` -> `MainActivity`. Therefor we have our `<data/>` and `variable` defined again. As you can see in `<include` we `bind:drawable` the exact same `variable` which is in both `XML` files.
The missing piece in our puzzle is the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="drawable"
            type="com.example.imagebuttonexperiment.DrawableContainer" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include_content"
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            bind:drawable = "@{drawable}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

---

**RESULT:**

[image: Result]

The final result is an `ImageButton` in the `MainActivity` that was included by another `Layout`. But the `Drawable` was chosen from the `MainActivity` and passed a Container to be shown in the included `Layout`. Magic isn't it!? ;)

---

**JAVA:**

And I will keep my word and provide you the JAVA version also.
The `XML` files and `gradle` will be the same, you only need to use `MainActivity.java` instead of `MainActivity.kt`, the same for `DrawableContainer.java` instead of `DrawableContainer.kt`.

Here is the same in green, `DrawableContainer.java`:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class DrawableContainer {

    public final Drawable customDrawable;

    public DrawableContainer(Drawable customDrawable) {
        this.customDrawable = customDrawable;
    }
}
```

And of course our `MainActivity.java`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.imagebuttonexperiment.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        mainBinding.setDrawable(new DrawableContainer(getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image)));
    }
}
```

---

**DOWNLOAD PROJECT:**

In addition I provide the project with both, `JAVA` and `Kotlin` classes in it. You just need to comment the content of the 2 classes grey you don't want. In example, if you want to use `Kotlin`, grey the content of `.java` files.

[Github Project](https://github.com/User96543169735/ImageButtonExperiment)

---

**Documentation & Tutorial:**

- [Databinding Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)
- [Youtube Tutorial: How to bind data?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QskuoJRfS9s&ab_channel=PRABEESHRK)

Comment: I added that and can now add this code without crashes to MainActivity.kt findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.black).setImageResource(R.drawable.pallet_pressed) (R.id.black refers to one of the buttons). However, the src is still not changed.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: That's somewhat a solution of my problem:
I have tried this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    colorDialog2=Dialog(this)
    colorDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_colors)
    colorDialog2.setTitle("Colors")

    firstRowColors=colorDialog2.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors)
    secondRowColors=colorDialog2.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors2)
    drawingView=findViewById<DrawingView>(R.id.drawingView)

    pressedColor= secondRowColors[0] as ImageButton
    pressedColor!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.pallet_pressed)

}
```

intead of this in Main.Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

colorDialog=findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.dialog_colors)
firstRowColors=colorDialog.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors)
secondRowColors=colorDialog.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_paint_colors2)
drawingView=findViewById<DrawingView>(R.id.drawingView)

pressedColor=secondRowColors[0] as ImageButton
pressedColor!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.pallet_pressed)}
```

And it worked, I managed to change the src however I wanted. (Only did this change didnt do the changes that the others provided) However, I am not even sure if this is a good practice. It works as a quick fix for sure tho.
I will look into DEX7RA's answer more later on.